# How to break down 2 datetime fields into 1 date and 2 times in Django Form?

Tags: django, django-forms

Okay so I am trying to make booking slots (like events/reservations).

```
#models.py
class BookingSlot(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField("Start Time")
    end_time = models.DateTimeField("End Time")
    location = models.ForeignKey(Court, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

As you can see the model has 2 datetime field. I want to make a form for creating booking slots whereby the form contains just one date and two times (assumption is that it is the same day). I am aware I could change my model but that is gonna create a few problems.

```
#forms.py
class BookingSlotForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BookingSlot
        fields = ['start_time', 'end_time', 'location']
```

I was wondering if there was a way I could edit my forms.py to do this. It seems like this is simple enough to do I am just unsure how to formulate a question for it.

```
#views.py
class CreateBookingForm(CreateView):
    template_name = 'app_book/create_bookings.html'
    form_class = BookingSlotForm
    success_message = 'Booking slot created'
```

Comment: It's quite doable - you'll want to exclude the `start_time` and `end_time` fields from the form and add your desired new fields, then customize the appropriate form methods to derive the model fields from the form fields. Before I write an example - do you want to support editing an existing model instance with this field, and if so how do you want to handle the possibility of a different date in the two model fields when doing that?

Comment: For editing It’s fine to just have the actual 2 date time fields but for creation I would like it to be different.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to:

1. Not include the model `DateTimeField`s in your model form
2. Instead, include a single form `DateField` and two `TimeField`s
3. When saving, populate the new instance's `DateTimeField` by combining the form fields

So something like this:

```
class BookingSlotForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BookingSlot
        fields = ['location']

    slot_date = forms.DateField()
    start_time = forms.TimeField()
    end_time = forms.TimeField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        slot = super(BookingSlotForm, self).save(commit=False)
        slot.start_time = datetime.combine(self.cleaned_data['slot_date'], self.cleaned_data['start_time'])
        slot.end_time = datetime.combine(self.cleaned_data['slot_date'], self.cleand_data['end_time'])
        if commit:
            slot.save()
        return slot
```

If your form has m2m fields you'll also need to call the `save_m2m()` method after saving the instance when `commit=True`. And I'm leaving out validation that the end time is after the start time - that's something you'd do with a custom `clean()` method on your model form, since it requires comparing the values of two fields.

If you want to use something like this for editing, you'd also need to override the form class's `__init__` method to copy the correct values from the instance, if any. That'd look something like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    if instance:
        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        # Here I'm not considering the possibility of the slot having different dates
        initial['slot_date'] = instance.start_time.date()
        initial['start_time'] = instance.start_time.time()
        initial['end_time'] = instance.end_time.time()
        kwargs['initial'] = initial
    super(BookingSlotForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```